# How to bind i18next-browser-languagedetector to Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin-js, i18next-browser-languagedetector

The Gradle project is set by the JS plugin:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("js") version("1.6.10")
}
```

and uses the `LEGACY` compilation backend:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    js(LEGACY) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My goal is to use the following dependencies in Kotlin sources:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(npm("i18next", "21.6.11"))
    implementation(npm("react-i18next", "11.15.4"))
    implementation(npm("i18next-browser-languagedetector", "6.1.3"))
}
```

It was pretty easy to describe JS-Kotlin bridging for the first two dependencies:

```kotlin
@JsModule("i18next")
@JsNonModule
external val i18next: I18n

external interface I18n {
    fun use(module: dynamic): I18n
}

@JsModule("react-i18next")
@JsNonModule
external val reactI18next: ReactI18next

external interface ReactI18next {
    val initReactI18next: dynamic
}
```

Unfortunately, the last one - `i18next-browser-languagedetector` - is driving me some nuts with its configuration. Something like this:

```kotlin
@JsModule("i18next-browser-languagedetector")
@JsNonModule
external val LanguageDetector: dynamic
```

doesn't work - the actual `LanguageDetector` provided by the declaration above is `{}`, so `i18next` doesn't consume it in Kotlin code (the JS code throws `You are passing a wrong module! Please check the object you are passing to i18next.use()`):

```kotlin
i18next.use(LanguageDetector) // fails
```

Can anyone please help me with a declaration of a JS-Kotlin bridge for the `LanguageDetector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by debugging a little bit I've managed to solve this JS-Kotlin bridging issue. The working solution is the following declaration:

```kotlin
@JsModule("i18next-browser-languagedetector")
@JsNonModule
external val i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector: I18nextBrowserLanguageDetector

external interface I18nextBrowserLanguageDetector {
    @JsName("default")
    val LanguageDetector: dynamic
}
```

Now it's possible to do first parts of the `i18next` initialization chain:

```kotlin
i18next
    .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.LanguageDetector)
    .use(reactI18next.initReactI18next)
    // ...
```

Unfortunately, it's difficult to say that I'm getting any intuition behind it (maybe because of my huge blind spots in JS) - so any additional clarification or explanations would be helpful still.

My biggest concern is that `LanguageDetector` from the declaration above should be a class, but it seems like no way to use something else rather than `dynamic` property. When I try to lift up the `@JsName("default")` annotation to mark some class protocol with it, it doesn't compile:

```kotlin
@JsModule("i18next-browser-languagedetector")
@JsNonModule
@JsName("default")
external class LanguageDetector
```

It's not possible to use a nested class inside of the interface as well in this case:

```kotlin
@JsModule("i18next-browser-languagedetector")
@JsNonModule
external interface I18nextBrowserLanguageDetector {
    @JsName("default")
    class LanguageDetector
}
```

So while it seems to be solved, it's super-frustrating still.